# how much gzipping burdens the client?

Tags: web-services, gzip

I'm optimizing our web service, and heard about gzip.

It would be good if we can reduce the network load using gzip, but I'm a little worried about how much unpacking overhead it'll bring to client.

Especially, our service uses javascript very often - which means that page rending in web browser will cost CPU time.

I cannot sure that taking cpu time to decompress gzip packet (instead of taking care of javascript) would bring positive effect to our service still.

Comment: It should be negligible overhead for any modern desktop/laptop computer (a statement purely pulled out of my read end). If you have a lot mobile users, it *may* be worth considering, but I'd still think it negligible. I'm interested in more scientific answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like HTML and javascript libraries, particularly static files, are good candidates for compression.  images aren't - they're already compressed.

Decompression of gzip compressed data is very fast compared to most internet connections - a quick test on my PC (AMD phenom 2.8GHz) results in decompression of about 170m/second, in a single core.  So a ~200k javascript file would be decompressed by a modern browser on a modern PC in about 2 milliseconds, and javascript typically compresses to about 25% of its original size (~35% if it is already minified).

Of course, just what proportion of your network load is made up of decompressed javascript is another matter.